# How can I utilize BLS.GOV API to extract data from their graphs to my website?

Tags: php, graph, data-extraction

I'm very new to programming and using API. I am currently working on a project to take data from `BLS.GOV` using their API to port the data to my website! so far, BLS has given me this code:

```
    $url = 'http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/';
    $method = 'POST';
    $query = array(
            'seriesid'  => array('LEU0254555900', 'APU0000701111'),
            'startyear' => '2002',
            'endyear'   => '2012'
    );
    $pd = json_encode($query);
    $contentType = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $contentLength = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($pd);

    $result = file_get_contents(
            $url, null, stream_context_create(
                    array(
                            'http' => array(
                                    'method' => $method,
                                    'header' => $contentType . "\r\n" . $contentLength . "\r\n",
                                    'content' => $pd
                            ),
                    )
            )
    );

    var_dump($http_response_header);
    var_dump($result);
```

How would I be able to grab graph data with PHP from this [link](http://www.bls.gov/ooh/healthcare/registered-nurses.htm#tab-5).